# Is it correct to request access token upon EVERY API call in my web app controllers?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, openid, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API on the backend, and a web app and phone app on the front end.
I am using Auth0 for OAuth/OpenId authentication on all three.
Both web API and web app are written in ASP .Net Core 1.1 MVC.

Every time I call the web API from the web app, I request an access token from Auth0. So, in every controller action that requires access to my API, I have:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
                var tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint,
                    new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),                
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _auth0Settings.ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _auth0Settings.ClientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("audience", _auth0Settings.ApiIdentifier),
                    }));
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? Or should I just perform this once when the web app fires up, and then store the access token in a global variable that I can call from all my controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call only once and reuse the token. When the token has expired you should request new token with refresh token. If u do not use refresh tokens u should redirect user to login page to reauthenticate or have some sort of auto-reauthenticate mechanism on web app.

Comment: Should an app check for expired using the expiry date within the token, or get a new token after a 401 or other authorisation error.

Comment: App should get a new token after 401 from web api. expiry date must be checked on web api. I have also updated slightly my answer..